# Categorize rows as first, last or in between

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, group-by, case

[image]

I have a table called `road_events`.

```
  create table road_events 
   (
    event_id number(5,0),
    road_id number(5,0),
    event_type nvarchar2(50),
    lifecycle_number number(5,0)
   );

insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (1,100,'RECONSTRUCTION',1);
insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (2,100,'RECONSTRUCTION',2);
insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (3,100,'INSPECTION',2);
insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (4,100,'INSPECTION',2);
insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (5,100,'INSPECTION',2);
insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (6,100,'INSPECTION',2);

insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (7,200,'INSPECTION',0);
insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (8,200,'RECONSTRUCTION',1);
insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (9,200,'INSPECTION',1);
insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (10,200,'INSPECTION',1);
insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (11,200,'RECONSTRUCTION',2);
insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (12,200,'INSPECTION',2);
insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (13,200,'INSPECTION',2);
insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (14,200,'INSPECTION',2);
insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (15,200,'RECONSTRUCTION',3);

insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (16,300,'RECONSTRUCTION',1);

insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (17,400,'INSPECTION',0);

insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (18,500,'RECONSTRUCTION',1);
insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (19,500,'RECONSTRUCTION',2);

insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (20,600,'INSPECTION',0);
insert into road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (21,600,'INSPECTION',0);
```

---

```
select
    event_id,
    road_id,
    substr(event_type,0,15) as event_type,
    lifecycle_number
from
    road_events
order by
    event_id

  EVENT_ID    ROAD_ID EVENT_TYPE      LIFECYCLE_NUMBER
---------- ---------- --------------- ----------------
         1        100 RECONSTRUCTION                 1
         2        100 RECONSTRUCTION                 2
         3        100 INSPECTION                     2
         4        100 INSPECTION                     2
         5        100 INSPECTION                     2
         6        100 INSPECTION                     2

         7        200 INSPECTION                     0
         8        200 RECONSTRUCTION                 1
         9        200 INSPECTION                     1
        10        200 INSPECTION                     1
        11        200 RECONSTRUCTION                 2
        12        200 INSPECTION                     2
        13        200 INSPECTION                     2
        14        200 INSPECTION                     2
        15        200 RECONSTRUCTION                 3

        16        300 RECONSTRUCTION                 1

        17        400 INSPECTION                     0

        18        500 RECONSTRUCTION                 1
        19        500 RECONSTRUCTION                 2

        20        600 INSPECTION                     0
        21        600 INSPECTION                     0
```

For each road, I would like to categorize the rows in each lifecycle with a `lifecycle_name` (in this order):

1. The rows in the last(max) lifecycle would be called `current lifecycle`
2. The rows in the first(min) lifecycle would be called `original lifecycle` (if applicable)
3. Any others would be called `past lifecycle` (if applicable)

It would look like this:

```
+----------+---------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+
| EVENT_ID | ROAD_ID |   EVENT_TYPE   | LIFECYCLE_NUMBER |   LIFECYCLE_NAME   |
+----------+---------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+
|        1 |     100 | RECONSTRUCTION |                1 | ORIGINAL LIFECYCLE |
|        2 |     100 | RECONSTRUCTION |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
|        3 |     100 | INSPECTION     |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
|        4 |     100 | INSPECTION     |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
|        5 |     100 | INSPECTION     |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
|        6 |     100 | INSPECTION     |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
+----------+---------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+
|        7 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                0 | ORIGINAL LIFECYCLE |
|        8 |     200 | RECONSTRUCTION |                1 | PAST LIFECYCLE     |
|        9 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                1 | PAST LIFECYCLE     |
|       10 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                1 | PAST LIFECYCLE     |
|       11 |     200 | RECONSTRUCTION |                2 | PAST LIFECYCLE     |
|       12 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                2 | PAST LIFECYCLE     |
|       13 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                2 | PAST LIFECYCLE     |
|       14 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                2 | PAST LIFECYCLE     |
|       15 |     200 | RECONSTRUCTION |                3 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
+----------+---------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+
|       16 |     300 | RECONSTRUCTION |                1 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
+----------+---------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+
|       17 |     400 | INSPECTION     |                0 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
+----------+---------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+
|       18 |     500 | RECONSTRUCTION |                1 | ORIGINAL LIFECYCLE |
|       19 |     500 | RECONSTRUCTION |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
+----------+---------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+
|       20 |     600 | INSPECTION     |                0 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
|       21 |     600 | INSPECTION     |                0 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
+----------+---------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

Is there a way to succinctly categorize the rows into `current lifecycle`, `original lifecycle`, and `past lifecycle`, where applicable?

I can think of some lengthy/cumbersome ways to do it with `case` statements and subqueries, but I'm looking for something a bit more elegant than that.

**Update:**

1. I've updated the question with a few more scenarios (roads 300-600). Credit goes to @markp for thinking of this.
2. @markp also highlighted that `current lifecycle` trumps `original lifecycle`.

Comment: What's the criteria for the *"First lifecycle"*? Seems fuzzy.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  As you might have noticed, we don't always have a record of the initial construction event of a road. Therefore, the lifecycle of the road begins at the earliest known record of the road. It could be construction or it could be an inspection of an existing road. The `lifecycle_number` column is based on a date column, which I didn't include in the question because I didn't think it was relevant (at the time).

Comment: OK, I hadn't noticed the numbers first and I thought you want it to be when 0. I suppose you want it for the lowest number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two window functions, `min()` and `max()` with the same window, over the `partition by road_id`:

```
select  event_id,
        road_id,
        event_type,
        lifecycle_number,
        case lifecycle_number
            when max(lifecycle_number) over (partition by road_id)
                then 'CURRENT LIFECYCLE'
            when min(lifecycle_number) over (partition by road_id)  
                then 'ORIGINAL LIFECYCLE'
                else 'PAST LIFECYCLE'
        end as LIFECYCLE_NAME
from    road_events re
order by event_id;
```

You could also use `first_value()` and `last_value()` window functions.

Test at [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=85c924cea97dff401a1cef66bf114ec1)

Comment: yeah, I thought about the case of all rows of a partition having the same lifecycle. It's trivial, you could change the order of `when` inside the case expression 9first max, then min), if you want to be shown as `CURRENT` and not as `ORIGINAL`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with finding the min/max lifecycle numbers for each road id, eg:

```
select road_id,
       min(lifecycle_number) as min_lcnum,
       max(lifecycle_number) as max_lcnum
from   road_events
group by road_id
order by 1;

 ROAD_ID | MIN_LCNUM | MAX_LCNUM
 ------- | --------- | ---------
     100 |         1 |         2
     200 |         0 |         3
     300 |         1 |         1
     400 |         0 |         0
     500 |         1 |         2
     600 |         0 |         0
```

Push this min/max code into a cte, add a relatively simple `case` statement and we get:

```
with
cte as
(select road_id,
        min(lifecycle_number) as min_lcnum,
        max(lifecycle_number) as max_lcnum
 from   road_events
 group by road_id)

select  re.event_id,
        re.road_id,
        re.event_type,
        re.lifecycle_number,

        case when re.lifecycle_number = c.max_lcnum
             then 'CURRENT LIFECYCLE'
             when re.lifecycle_number = c.min_lcnum
             then 'ORIGINAL LIFECYCLE'
             else 'PAST LIFECYCLE'
        end as LIFECYCLE_NAME

from    road_events re

join    cte c
on      c.road_id = re.road_id

order by re.event_id;

 EVENT_ID | ROAD_ID | EVENT_TYPE     | LIFECYCLE_NUMBER | LIFECYCLE_NAME    
 -------- | ------- | -------------- | ---------------- | ------------------
        1 |     100 | RECONSTRUCTION |                1 | ORIGINAL LIFECYCLE
        2 |     100 | RECONSTRUCTION |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE 
        3 |     100 | INSPECTION     |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE 
        4 |     100 | INSPECTION     |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE 
        5 |     100 | INSPECTION     |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE 
        6 |     100 | INSPECTION     |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE 

        7 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                0 | ORIGINAL LIFECYCLE
        8 |     200 | RECONSTRUCTION |                1 | PAST LIFECYCLE    
        9 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                1 | PAST LIFECYCLE    
       10 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                1 | PAST LIFECYCLE    
       11 |     200 | RECONSTRUCTION |                2 | PAST LIFECYCLE    
       12 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                2 | PAST LIFECYCLE    
       13 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                2 | PAST LIFECYCLE    
       14 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                2 | PAST LIFECYCLE    
       15 |     200 | RECONSTRUCTION |                3 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE 

       16 |     300 | RECONSTRUCTION |                1 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE 

       17 |     400 | INSPECTION     |                0 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE 

       18 |     500 | RECONSTRUCTION |                1 | ORIGINAL LIFECYCLE
       19 |     500 | RECONSTRUCTION |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE 

       20 |     600 | INSPECTION     |                0 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE 
       21 |     600 | INSPECTION     |                0 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE
```

Here's a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b7af2a801393b3df753d28e83ee8d682)